# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in recursion

Tags: java, recursion

i know after debugging that sons list is changed 
i don't know why it is changed 
and this modification causes me problems in my algorithm

```
public class IDS extends Algo {
public State found = null;

public IDS(char[][] input, int size) {
    super(input, size);
}

public String solve() {
    State root = new State(0, 0, 0, 0, "", 0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < size * size; i++) {
        found = DLS(root, i);
        if (found != null) {
            return found.path + " " + found.dist;
        }
    }
    return "no path";
}

private State DLS(State node, int depth) {
    if (depth == 0 && super.inp[node.row][node.col] == 'G') {
        return node;
    }
    if (depth > 0) {
        // List<State> sons = super.find_neighbors(node.row, node.col, node.prod_time);
        // for (int j = 0; j < sons.size(); j++) {
        //State cur = sons.get(j);
        for(State cur : super.find_neighbors(node.row, node.col, node.prod_time)){
            cur.addCost(node.dist);
            cur.path = cur.addpath(node.path);
            found = DLS(cur, depth - 1);
            if (found != null) {
                return found;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

here is the abstract class:

```
abstract class Algo {
public static Map<Integer,String> ways = new TreeMap<>();
protected char[][]inp;
protected int size;
private Map<Character,Integer>costs = new HashMap<>();
public List<State>sons = new ArrayList<>();

public Algo(){}
public Algo(char[][] input,int size){
   inp = input;
    this.size = size;
    ways.put(1,"R");
    ways.put(2,"RD");
    ways.put(3,"D");
    ways.put(4,"LD");
    ways.put(5,"L");
    ways.put(6,"LU");
    ways.put(7,"U");
    ways.put(8,"RU");
    costs.put('R',1);
    costs.put('D',3);
    costs.put('H',10);
    costs.put('G',0);
    costs.put('S',0);
}
private void addDirection(int row,int col,int prod, int loc){
    int cos = costs.get(inp[row][col]);
    State s = new State(row,col,0,prod,"",loc,cos);
    sons.add(s);
}
public abstract String solve();
//gets the parent i,j and the prod_t of the sons
public List<State> find_neighbors(int i, int j,int prod_t){
    List<String>openD = new ArrayList<>();
    sons.clear();

    if(j+1 < size) {//right
        if (inp[i][j + 1] != 'W') {
            addDirection(i, j + 1, prod_t, 1);
            openD.add("R");
        }
    }
    if(i-1 >= 0) {
        if (inp[i - 1][j] != 'W') {//up
            addDirection(i - 1, j, prod_t, 7);
            openD.add("U");
        }
    }
    if(i+1 < size) {
        if (inp[i + 1][j] != 'W') {//down
            addDirection(i + 1, j, prod_t, 3);
            openD.add("D");
        }
    }
    if(j-1 >= 0){
        if(inp[i][j-1]!='W'){//left
            addDirection(i,j-1,prod_t,5);
            openD.add("L");
        }
    }

    if(openD.contains("L")){
        if(openD.contains("U")){
            if(inp[i-1][j-1]!='W'){
                addDirection(i-1,j-1,prod_t,6);
            }
        }
        if(openD.contains("D")){
            if(inp[i+1][j-1]!='W'){
                addDirection(i+1,j-1,prod_t,4);
            }
        }
    }
    if(openD.contains("R")){
        if(openD.contains("U")) {
            if (inp[i - 1][j + 1] != 'W') {
                addDirection(i - 1, j + 1, prod_t, 8);
            }
        }
        if(openD.contains("D")){
            if(inp[i+1][j+1]!='W'){
                addDirection(i+1,j+1,prod_t,2);
            }
        }
    }
    return sons;
}
```

}

the exception just helped me know the list has modified however still don't know why :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
at IDS.DLS(IDS.java:33)
at IDS.solve(IDS.java:17)
at ex1.main(ex1.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: Do you understand what a `ConcurrentModification` indicates, and what causes it to be thrown?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437139/java-java-util-concurrentmodificationexception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*super.find_neighbors* modifies and returns the *sons* list. Inside your loop the method *DLS* is recursively called which calls *super.find_neighbors* again (modifying the same list that is currently iterated one recursion above). Because the list is changed during you iterate over it the exception is thrown.

Comment: i understand that this function causes the problem... i will try to create a copy of the list so that sons won't held a pointer to the list in Algo class. if you have any creational idea that will solve it i will be glad to know about it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are doings a sons.clear() inside Algo.find_neighbours() That will cause the ConcurrentModification in the loop. Moreover, since find_neighbours() always return an empty List, what's the poingt in trying to iterate over it?

Comment: always return an empty list?

Comment: No, my bad, I missed part of the code, but the clear() inside it will cause the ConcurrentModification anyway in the loop.